# Vue-cli 3 - Material design icons installation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

How do I install [`vue-material-design-icons`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-material-design-icons) in my [Vue CLI 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/) project? I've been trying to use it without any good result, and I can't find any tutorial about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Usage

The full list of available icons are found at https://materialdesignicons.com/. On first load, the site may take a few seconds to display the icon preview list at the bottom of the page. Hover over the desired icon, and make note of the icon name shown at the top of the tooltip. Alternatively, click the icon preview to show the icon details in a popup. You can import the icon in your Vue component using this format:

```
import FooIcon from 'vue-material-design-icons/__ICON_NAME__.vue'
```

For example, this screenshot shows the tooltip for the icon named `auto-fix`:

[image]

In your Vue component, you would import the icon like this:

```
import AutoFixIcon from 'vue-material-design-icons/auto-fix.vue'
```

and declare it as a local component:

```
export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  components: {
    AutoFixIcon
  }
}
```

and then use it in your component's template:

```
<template>
  <AutoFixIcon/>
</template>
```

## Tutorial

1. Create a new `vue-cli` project (e.g., named `vue-md-icons-demo`), and pick the `default` setup when prompted:

   ```
   vue create vue-md-icons-demo
   ```
2. CD into the newly created project directory:

   ```
   cd vue-md-icons-demo
   ```
3. Install `vue-material-design-icons` package from NPM:

   ```
   npm i -S vue-material-design-icons
   ```
4. In `src/main.js`, import the styles for the icons:

   ```
     import Vue from 'vue'
     import App from './App.vue'
   + import 'vue-material-design-icons/styles.css'
   ```
5. In `src/App.vue` (or in your component file), import the desired icon to be used (see **Usage** above), and declare it as a local component. In this case, we'll import the icon named `air-conditioner`:

   ```
     <script>
     import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
   + import AirConditionerIcon from 'vue-material-design-icons/air-conditioner.vue'

     export default {
       name: 'app',
       components: {
   -     HelloWorld
   +     HelloWorld,
   +     AirConditionerIcon
       }
     }
   ```
6. In `src/App.vue`, declare the icon element in the template (i.e., `<AirConditionerIcon/>` in this case):

   ```
   <template>
     <AirConditionerIcon/>
   </template>
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0y1z3qwr4l)

Answer (score 0):

The official material design icon guide:
https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/vue

Install

```
npm install @mdi/js @jamescoyle/vue-icon
```

Import to your project

```
import SvgIcon from '@jamescoyle/vue-icon'
import { mdiAccount } from '@mdi/js'
```

Component example:

```
<template>
  <svg-icon type="mdi" :path="path"></svg-icon>
</template>


<script>
import SvgIcon from '@jamescoyle/vue-icon'
import { mdiAccount } from '@mdi/js'

export default {
    name: "my-cool-component",

    components: {
        SvgIcon
    },

    data() {
        return {
            path: mdiAccount,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: wish to know how to add this in nuxt 3 composition API and typescript